# How truncate a decimal part?

Tags: c#, algorithm, class

I'm trying to truncate a decimal part.

I mean create a function which do this.

1/9 ~ 0.11111111111111

So, if in the function set that wants to pick 5 decimals, must returns 0.11111

I was doing this using strings, but I guess is not a good idea. Is possible do that using math operations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
Math.Truncate
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf.aspx

Edit: My version of a suitable method (though Gary has already shared one below)

```
    public static double Truncate(double number, int digits) 
    { 
        double conversionFactor = (Math.Pow(10.0, digits));
        return Math.Truncate(number * conversionFactor) / conversionFactor;
    }
```

Comment: There's an eerie similarity between this edit 3 hours ago and an answer posted 4 hours ago...

Comment: @Garry-vass:I had answered much earlier (I was the first to answer, it says 5hrs ago right now). I hadn't supplied a code example so I thought I should. When posting I saw that you have already added one(in my edit I have even mentioned that you have already shared an example). I hadnt seen yours until then. Does this break site rules?

Comment: A considerate response would be if you think someone's answer is valuable, you would upvote it rather than replicating their code into your own answer and changing variable names.

Comment: @Garry-vass: for the last time, i didnt use your code...I am not that bad that i cant put together a function...but if you are so offended i am willing to take it out.

Comment: C'mon guys, don't fight! And thank you so much for your support.

Answer (score 2):

To truncate the decimal part of a given `value` by `nDecimals`, just use:

```
value = Math.Truncate(value * Math.Pow(10, nDecimals)) / Math.Pow(10, nDecimals);
```

so if `value = 1/9` and `nDecimals = 5`, it returns `0.11111`

Answer (score 1):

Since [Math.Truncate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.truncate.aspx) does not allow to specify the number of digits you want to keep, you would have to multiply with `10^d` first, truncate and divide by `10^d` again, where d is the number of decimal digits you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method like...

```
 private double TruncateAt(double number, double decimals)
    {
        double factor = Math.Pow(10, decimals);
        return Math.Truncate(number*factor)/factor;
    }
```

And call the method by

```
double x = TruncateAt(1.0 / 9.0, 5);
```

If your program uses the same factor consistently, you may with to make it a const and get the performance improvement...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, especially since I haven't touched C# for awhile, but I *think* you could use `Math.Round`? Kinda like the way it is used [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx).

So, maybe try `Math.Round(0.111111111, 6);`?